# Keep decorator on override method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've got a parent class with a method used many times and override all the time. This method has a decorator. I would like to reuse the decorator each time I override the methode without using super() or rewrite de decorator

```
def decorator(method):
   def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print("how are you ?")
      method(self, *args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper

class A:
    @decorator
    def method_a(*args, **kwargs):
       pass

class B(A):
    def method_a(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Fine thanks !")

class_b = B()
class_b.method_a()

# How are you ?
# Fine thanks !
```

Comment: did you miss `def` before both `method_a`?

Comment: Indeed. I do the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to make an additional function, e.g. `_method_a` that contains the core of a function, and decorated `method_a` that only calls the other one. In the child classes you can reimplement `_method_a`, while leaving `method_a` from inheritance, thus still decorated.

```
class A:
    @decorator
    def method_a(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._method_a(args, kwargs)

    def _method_a(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

class B(A):
    def _method_a(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Fine thanks !")
```

Comment: I don't understand how method_a will be call ?

Comment: As normal. It is inherited from A - `class_b.method_a()`, just like in your example.

Comment: Obviously. I just test it nd it works ! Thanks !